# Bash backup wont work

Tags: bash, backup

I'm trying to gzip a file using a script but it will not work and continues to throw errors. Can someone please giveme some guidance on what is wrong with this script?

```
DEFAULTDIRECTORY=”/Backup”
if [ -d "$DEFAULTDIRECTORY" ]; then 
mkdir -p /backup 
fi # Makes directory if the directory does not exist

# Set the timestamp for the backup
TIMESTAMP=`date +%Y%m%d.%H%M`

# let the user choose what they want to backup
echo -n "Select the file or directory you want to backup" 
read Chosendata 



# read the backup file name file
echo -n "Select the file name" 
read FNAME

# start the backup.
echo -e "Starting backup"

# compress the directory and files, direct the tar.gz file to your destination directory
tar -vczf ${FNAME}-${TIMESTAMP}.tar.gz ${Chosendata} > ${DEFAULTDIRECTORY}

# end the backup.
echo -e "Backup complete"
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're experiencing?  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Is that a verbatim copy of your script? 'Cause the quotes on the first line a wrong: They are U+201D (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) rather than what you probably wanted: U+0022 (QUOTATION MARK). On the other hand, that string doesn't need any quotes at all. Other than that, I recommend [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting output from the tar command to `DEFAULTDIRECTORY` isn't doing what the comment specifies.

I think what you want to do is save the file in the `DEFAULTDIRECTORY`.

Change the line

```
tar -vczf ${FNAME}-${TIMESTAMP}.tar.gz ${Chosendata} > ${DEFAULTDIRECTORY}
```

to

```
tar -vczf $DEFAULTDIRECTORY/${FNAME}-${TIMESTAMP}.tar.gz ${Chosendata}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to negate this test `if [ -d "$DEFAULTDIRECTORY" ]; then` -> `if [ ! -d "$DEFAULTDIRECTORY" ]; then`. You should not use redirect with tar command. instead you should prefix your tar.gz file with it:

```
tar -vczf $DEFAULTDIRECTORY/${FNAME}-${TIMESTAMP}.tar.gz ${Chosendata}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEFAULTDIRECTORY="/Backup"

# Makes directory if the directory does not exist
# Here you had an inverted statement: use "if [ ! -d ... ] then" or "[ -d ... ] ||" 
[ -d "${DEFAULTDIRECTORY}" ] || mkdir -p "${DEFAULTDIRECTORY}"

# Set the timestamp for the backup
# For subshell command you can use `...` or $(...)
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M)

# Let the user choose what they want to backup
# You can use the -p (prompt) option instead of using echo
read -p "Select the file or directory you want to backup: " CHOSENDATA 

# Read the backup file name
read -p "Select the file name: " FILENAME

# Start the backup.
echo "Starting backup"

# Compress the directory, direct the tar.gz file to your destination directory
# tar 'create' ' zip' 'verbose' 'force' <The output filename> <The data you want to backup>
tar -czvf ${DEFAULTDIRECTORY}/${FILENAME}-${TIMESTAMP}.tar.gz ${CHOSENDATA}

# End the backup.
echo "Backup complete"
```